# how to go from angular event to jquery selector

Tags: angularjs

I know this is bad design but would like to introduce angular to a current project. I would like sayHello to be able to determine whether the element has the class 'is-a-favorite'

```
<div ng-click="sayHello(29, $event)" class="is-a-favorite" data-type="location" data-global-id="29" data-make-disappear="false">&nbsp;</div>

$scope.sayHello=function(global_id,event){
  //var selector=???
  if(selector.hasClass('is-a-favorite')){
      console.log("this is-a-favorite");
  }
};
```

How would (or could) I get a reference to current DOM element to query via hasClass?

thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clicked element is available as `$event.target`, so you could check `$($event.target).attr('class')` or something similar.

EDIT: actually, what you'd want is to check `$($event.target).hasClass('is-a-favorite')`

Comment: yes, perfect thx. I know not supposed to do this but it might allow us to start using angular which would be cool